# When creating a view in MySQL, can update commands be run on that view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a HUGE query with 5 or 6 join, and want to turn this into a view. But, I need too be able to update this view. Is this possible?

By update, I mean, run an SQL UPDATE command, alter a value, and then let the changed values filter through to the appropriate tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certain views can be updatable in MySQL, but there are constraints with them. At the very least, there must be a 1 to 1 relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table.